# I would like to use IF or CASE in a custom query connection with Big Query and Data Studio, is it possible?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I would like to pass a param value by URL in my data studio to filter its content OR NOT.

What I thought was some like this:

I created a parameter called `user_id` and allowed to be modified in report URL;

IF there is no param in the URL, don't do a `where` in the connector with Big Query and get all the content, if there is a param (user_id), do the `where` and create a filter of the data for me.

Is it possible? Or in another form?

```
CASE @user_id
  WHEN NULL THEN SELECT * FROM `my_table.table2.my_table_name`

  ELSE SELECT * FROM `my_table.table2.my_table_name` where user_id = @user_id

  END
```

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this problem with the query below:

```
SELECT *
FROM `my_table.table2.my_table_name`

WHERE CASE 
  WHEN @user_id != "" THEN user_id = @user_id
  ELSE user_id IS NOT NULL
END
```